# Como funciona o acesso a struct por ponteiro de ponteiros e por uma cópia do ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Em `push1()` eu passei por parâmetro o endereço de memória, no `push2()` passei uma copia do ponteiro, porém não entendi a diferença como cada uma acessa a `struct`?

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef Node *No;
typedef Node Elem;

void push1(struct Node** headRef, int data)
{
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = newNode;
}

int push2(No *li, int data)
{
    Elem *no = (Elem*) malloc(sizeof(Elem));

    no->data = data;
    no->next = (*li);
    *li = no;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int i = 0;

    struct Node *head = NULL;
    push1(&head, arr[i]);

    No *li = (No*) malloc(sizeof(No));
    push2(li, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diferença está nesta linha:

```
typedef Node *No;
```

Quando você usa um `typedef` está dizendo que quer um nome para representar alguma outra definição existente que é colocada logo antes do nome.

Então nesse exemplo o nome `No` na verdade é o mesmo que `Node *`, ou mais precisamente `struct Node *` já que `Node` está no mesmo *namespace* ali não precisou colocar a especificação.

Então quando você escrever:

```
int push2(No *li, int data)
```

Na verdade é o mesmo que escrever:

```
int push2(struct Node **li, int data)
```

Portanto é igual a:

```
void push1(struct Node **headRef, int data)
```

Este código mostra melhor a diferença entre transmitir o resultado obtido dentro da função por um parâmetro que é passado como referência ou retornado no fim da execução da função. Na prática o resultado é o mesmo mas a forma é diferente, o que usa o `return` haverá uma cópia, o que pode ser bom ou ruim de acordo com o contexto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node *No;
typedef struct Node Elem;

void push1(struct Node** headRef, int data) {
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = newNode;
}

No *push2(No *li, int data) {
    Elem *no = malloc(sizeof(Elem));
    no->data = data;
    no->next = (*li);
    *li = no;
    return li;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int i = 0;
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    push1(&head, arr[i]);
    printf("%d", head->data);
    No *li = malloc(sizeof(No));
    No *result = push2(li, arr[i]);
    printf("%d", (*li)->data);
    printf("%d", (*result)->data);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qzjgbe). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sakbkriv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ReturnXReference.c).